# Why is NHibernate AutoFlush check so expensive?

Tags: nhibernate

In practice we are finding the default NHibernate (v2.0 & 2.1) FlushMode=Auto to be extremely expensive. Reviewing the NHibernate source suggests that the algorithms for determining what needs to be flushed rely on brute-force of looping through all entities in session, and this occurs for every query run in a transaction.

In some production scenario with updates on many items, with multiple queries we have seen the process 100 times longer with FlushMode=Auto compared to FlushMode=Commit.

Any thoughts/advice/best practices for usage of FlushMode when performing 'complex' session logic involving multiple updates, multiple queries etc.

Any ideas on optimizing the AutoFlush algorithms in nHibernate?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724307/nhibernate-poor-performance-on-auto-flush-events

Comment: yep... actually the same issue :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This slowness is a known issue and is tracked in NH as [NH-1365/GitHib Issue 857](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/857)

There are three flush modes in NH:

- FlushMode.Auto = Flush when needed (on commit and before queries, if needed). This is the default.
- FlushMode.Commit = flush on commit of NH transaction only
- FlushMode.Never = never flush (until Flush is called). This will [still go to DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432087/nhibernate-flushmode-on-save) on insert of entities that use native (identity) PK generator.

Comment: Thanks, glad to know its a known issue. Sad to know that it is a know issue for over a year! I appreciate that there are plenty of ways to re-arrange code to limit the number of flushes performed. Nonetheless it seems like the flushing performance in Nhibernate is a lot slower than it should be.

Comment: There's also `FlushMode.Always`: the session is flushed before any query is executed, expensive https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-pitfalls-flush-mode. And also `FlushMode.Unspecified` which is a special null value; not sure if it can actually be used.